# SET X-AUTH-TOKEN in WSO2 ESB

Tags: http-headers, token, xauth, wso2-esb

We need to set the http header property `X-Auth-Token` in ESB before sending  it to endpoint.  The endpoint authenticates this token.

When we `X-Auth-Token` in header property it's not working.

Can you suggest the way to set the X-Auth-Token property in http header in WSO2

Comment: Header mediator is working , the problem is with the cert , we had imported the destination cert into the trusted store of ESB and it is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You use the following config to do this. Make sure the scope is set to transport.

```
<property name="X-Auth-Token" scope="transport" value="XXXXX" />
```